# Кто вызвал abort()?

Tags: c++, linux

На целевой системе программа вылетает при некоторых входных данных с exit кодом 134 (SIGABORT). Возможности запустить под отладчиком нет.

Каким образом (кроме пристального изучения кода) найти место (функцию, в идеале callstack), где сработал вызов abort()?

В исходниках прямого вызова abort() нет. Вывод [backtrace_symbols_fd](https://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols_fd) в обработчике сигнала показывает цепочку вызовов начиная с abort() (внутри стандартной библиотеки), кончая обработчиком сигнала (вызовы, предшествующие abort() отсутствуют).

Comment: @Abyx в этом загвоздка - если в обработчике сигнала вызывать backtrace_symbols_fd, то он показывает вызовы начиная с abort, заканчивая обработчиком (без предшествующих abort вызовов).

Comment: сигналы могут приходить извне

Comment: Так а что с дампами, есть ли возможность их получить? И что происходит при запуске с этими же входными данными на нецелевой системе, где можно запускать отладчик?

Comment: @VTT с дампами не работал, попробую погуглить. На машине разработчика проблем не наблюдается (но есть много заглушек для реальных устройств, с которыми работает программа, возможно поэтому работает нормально).

Comment: SIGABRT может сгенериться стандартной библиотекой при обнаружении повреждений в структуре кучи и при неперехваченном исключении. Если явных throw в коде нет, то остаётся разнос памяти или несбалансированные new/delete.

Answer (score 7):

Методом деления отрезка пополам. Вполне серьёзно. Занимаюсь разработкой реал-тайм систем, в которых никакие отладчики использовать невозможно.  Поэтому, когда возникает такая ситуация, поступаю следующим образом:

1. Пытаюсь понять хотя бы, в какой функции происходит прерывание.
2. Делю текст функции на 10 (ориентировочно) частей с помощью операторов вида *printf("01\n"); - printf("10\n");*
3. Запускаю программу, получаю локализацию в первом приближении.
4. Полученный отрезок делю опять, пока не дохожу до интервала в одну строку исходного текста. Обычно на это хватает 2-3 итерации.

Comment: printf-отладка - мягко выражаясь, не особо дельный совет

Comment: @VTT Это вы еще отладки на слух не видели, когда надо отлаживаться, а из средств общения с пользователем только генератор звука доступен :)

Comment: @VTT В реальности, разумеется, я пользуюсь не printf, а syslog. Но, в данном случае, это не принципиально. Сислог забираю по FTP, анализирую дома и делаю удалённый апгрейт системы. Так Вам больше нравится? :-)

Comment: @Sergey Нет, ведение логов в целях отладки - последнее дело. Это однозначный индикатор больших проблем с разработкой.

Comment: **ведение логов в целях отладки - последнее дело**  ну я этим последним делом занимаюсь последние лет 20. Так что, разрешите с Вами не согласиться. Нильс Бор как-то сказал, что все науки разделяются на две: физику и коллекционирование марок. Вот и про отладку RT систем я хочу сказать, что все способы отладки RT разделяются на два: мозг + лог и коллекционирование марок.

Comment: И что, за 20 лет не было ситуаций, когда вставка принта меняет поведение и проблема перестает воспроизводиться, или когда проблема на работающей системе воспроизводится раз в месяц, так что принтом ее локализовывать можно было бы до пенсии, или когда вообще доступа к системе нет? А как же альтернативные подходы, верификация там или тесты?

Comment: 1) Было. 2) Очень часто бывает. 3) **верификация там или тесты** - конкретный пример привожу. Делал ПО для девайса, который нынче ставят в автобусы, троллейбусы, мусоровозки, машины СМП и т.д. Одним из модулей там был модуль, который предупреждал водителя о подходе к одной из перечисленных в списке зон, попаданию в неё и покиданию оной.  Поскольку зоны - не прямоугольные, а "попадание" определено довольно туманно, то задача нетривиальна... Я ложил сей девайс на сиденье своей машины, ехал по городу, потом возвращался на работу и анализировал логи.

Comment: Вы не могли бы мне подсказать, какие именно **верификации там или тесты** мне надо было использовать, вместо мотания по городу и анализа логов, что бы потом меня заказчик не убил?

Comment: Кстати да, **вообще доступа к системе нет** - это почти 100% случаев. Системы RT должны быть защищены.

Comment: На новых процессорах Интел можно звать встроенный трассировщик процессора. Помимо этого есть разные утилиты, strace, ptrace, gdb, ...

Comment: @0andriy **На новых процессорах Интел** В этой теме речь шла, в основном, о RT системах. А это, как правило - ARM и PowerPC.

Comment: @0andriy **разные утилиты, strace, ptrace, gdb** - TS ясно сказал: "Возможности запустить под отладчиком нет."

Comment: ETM есть в ARM.

Comment: Дело не в том, что есть, а чего нет на ARM / PowerPC / x86...
Вопрос очень простой - куда Вы будете подключать свой JTAG, когда отлаживаемый объект летит по небу / едет по городу / управляет плазменной резкой в реальном времени ?! Когда идёт отладка системы, работающей с РЕАЛЬНЫМ миром, как правило, подключение любых отладочных средств становится очень проблематичным.

Comment: Сама идея о том, что программу можно **приостановить**, посмотреть значение переменных, стека и т.д. она (эта идея) абсолютно недопустима в реальном времени. Потому что приостановка любого процесса означает конец работы всей системы.